# $\int f\,d\mu = \int f\,d\nu$ for all continuous $f$ implies that $\mu = \nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite positive measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, 1]$ such that$$\int f\,d\mu = \int f\,d\nu$$whenever $f$ is real-valued and continuous on $[0, 1]$. Do we necessarily have that $\mu = \nu$?

Comment: Yes. One way to see it is by Riesz-Markov representation theorem.

Comment: Well, if $\;f\equiv0\;$ I think you'll find it is not.

Comment: For *all* $f$ continuous?

Comment: And now the question at 100 kopecks: what could possibly be a source on measure theory that does not explain that the result holds and why?

Comment: @Did it's from Richard Bass's "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" and it's from one of the early chapters immediately after measures are introduced. All of these measure theory questions from the new users have come from a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Because then the integrals are certainly equal for every *bounded*, real-valued, continuous $f$, which is tantamount to saying that the constant sequence $\mu, \mu, \dots$ converges weakly to $\nu$, and, similarly, that the constant sequence $\nu, \nu, \dots$ converges weakly to $\mu$. This implies, by the Portmanteau Theorem that, for all closed sets $C$, $\mu(C) = \nu(C)$. Since the collection of closed sets contains the sample space $[0,1]$, is closed to finite intersections (indeed, to intersections of arbitrary cardinality), and generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and since $\mu, \nu$ are finite, this implies, by the [uniqueness of measures theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures), that $\mu = \nu$.